# How do i pick a start and end frame to scale key frames?

Tags: transforms, keyframes, dopesheet

I'm making a visualizer for my own music. I find sometimes when I do this, the keyframes come out as if my audio was slowed down 300% or so. I think this is just a glitch because the geometry of what I'm working on is too complex and blender seems to lag the keyframes due to my machine's poor performance. So I'm trying to shrink the keyframes so that the spikes for the 4x4 kickdrum line up with the audio. I've tried scaling in the dope sheet but it seems that I need to scale and grab multiple times and can never get it right.

Is there a way to pick the start point of all my key frames and an end point and have it scale accordingly?